# Why console applications do not have SynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am starting using an external library (SDK) that requires a context(SynchronizationContext) at initialization, so my first approach on testing it was by writing a simple console app, but, when I try to use `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null.

```
string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.KEY];

if (DLL.Init(key, SynchronizationContext.Current))
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{DLL.IsInitialized()} Press enter to close...");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine($"{DLL.IsInitialized()} Press enter to close...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Would you mind helping me to understand the usage of ``SynchronizationContext``` and why is not initialized at the console app?

**Update**
This question could be similar to -> [Why the default SynchronizationContext is not captured in a Console App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686862/why-the-default-synchronizationcontext-is-not-captured-in-a-console-app), but, I do not understand, why a console app needs a custom context?

Comment: Please check out this blog post regarding `SynchronizationContext` in console application: https://veganhunter.net/2016/12/02/synchronizationcontext-in-console-applications/

Comment: "I do not understand, why a console app needs a custom context" Because it doesn't have a WPF or WF maintained synchronization context.

Comment: Any suggestions of how and where SynchronizationContext is implemented and used for? thanks