# Explanation on Main thread Execution with await keyword

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have read a dozen articles about async/await and they all have been a great read. But in all those articles some confusions/questions weren't addressed. I have seen on this forum too [(this awesome post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681101/106356) but I haven't got clear explanation,so I am seeking your profound knowledge on the matter.

**Example**

In the below example of Console App as synchronization context is not maintained  the thread ID's are returned namely 1 and 5.

(*A similar example with GUI would run on **the same thread** as synchronization context is maintained there.*)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncConcept
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: " + (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async void AsyncMethod()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            Console.WriteLine("AsyncMethod Thread: " + (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

When we use await keyword with let's say an I/O call or an API call, does await operation happens on Main thread only?

a) If yes, the how come the Main thread (UI thread in case of GUI) continue with remainder of the method simultaneously ?

b) If No, then it violates the No thread spawn theory of async and await.

Comment: A console app does not have a synchronization context.  So this is entirely normal.  Pretty much the reason why a console app is so different from a GUI app, there's nothing much subtle about Application.Run().  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52686862/17034

Comment: the concern here is the awaitable task continues to be on Main thread ?

Answer (score 1):

> When we use await keyword with let's say an I/O call or an API call, does await operation happens on Main thread only?

`await` happens on whatever thread is running that method. In this case, `AsyncMethod` is invoked on the main thread, and the `await` happens on the main thread. If `AsyncMethod` was called by a UI thread, then the `await` would happen on the UI thread.

I think you are thinking that `await` somehow "runs" the asynchronous operation, but that is not at all what happens. What I mean by [the `await` "happening"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) is that the `await`:

1. Checks to see whether its awaitable is completed (in this case, the "awaitable" is the task returned from `Task.Delay`). If it has already completed, it continue executing the method synchronously.
2. If the awaitable is not complete, `await` will (by default) capture the current context, and then use that to schedule the continuation of that method to run when the awaitable completes. Then the `await` returns.

Note that if the awaitable is not complete, then the method returns. In the normal case, it would return an incomplete task that completes when the `async` method completes; in this case, there is no return type so the calling code cannot easily know when the `async` method completes.

> a) If yes, the how come the Main thread (UI thread in case of GUI) continue with remainder of the method simultaneously ?

Since the awaitable is not complete, `await` returns from the method. The rest of the method will run when the awaitable completes.

Comment: Stephnen : So, Main/UI thread initiates `await` operation. When `awaitable` is not complete the Thread would pass on to the next line of instructions(the remainder of the method) not related to the await.But in the meantime, that incomplete await (_which certainly will be completed in some period of time_) will run on which thread ? The same thread ?

Comment: If you mean the awaitable, the technical answer is "however it's implemented." In the general case, it doesn't "run" anywhere; [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).