# Running async functions in parallel from list of interfaces

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a similair question to [Running async methods in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634376/running-async-methods-in-parallel/38634509) in that I wish to run a number of functions from a list of functions in parallel.

I have noted in a number of comments online it is mentioned that if you have another await in your methods, Task.WhenAll() will not help as Async methods are not parallel.

I then went ahead and created a thread for each using function call with the below (the number of parallel functions will be small typically 1 to 5):

```
public interface IChannel
{
    Task SendAsync(IMessage message);
}

public class SendingChannelCollection
{
    protected List<IChannel> _channels = new List<IChannel>();

    /* snip methods to add channels to list etc */

    public async Task SendAsync(IMessage message)
    {
        var tasks = SendAll(message);

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.AsParallel().Select(async task => await task));
    }

    private IEnumerable<Task> SendAll(IMessage message)
    {
        foreach (var channel in _channels)
            yield return channel.SendAsync(message, qos);
    }
}
```

I would like to double check I am not doing anything horrendous with code smells or bugs as i get to grips with what I have patched together from what i have found online. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *if you have another await in your methods, Task.WhenAll() will not help as Async methods are not parallel.* This statement is wrong. Async methods can be parallel if they are CPU-bound, and definitely can be concurrent if they are either CPU-bound or I/O-bound. It depends on how you start and then `await` the associated tasks. If you `await` each task immediately after its creation: no concurrency. If you create them all and then await them: concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compare the behaviour of your line:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.AsParallel().Select(async task => await task));
```

in contrast with:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

What are you delegating to PLINQ in the first case? Only the `await` operation, which does basically nothing - it invokes the `async`/`await` machinery to wait for one `task`. So you're setting up a PLINQ query that does all the heavy work of partitioning and merging the results of an operation that amounts to "do nothing until this `task` completes". I doubt that is what you want.

> If you have another await in your methods, Task.WhenAll() will not help as Async methods are not parallel.

I couldn't find that in any of the answers to the linked questions, except for one comment under the question itself. I'd say that it's probably a misconception, stemming from the fact that `async`/`await` doesn't magically turn your code into concurrent code. But, assuming you're in an environment without a custom `SynchronizationContext` (so not an ASP or WPF app), continuations to `async` functions will be scheduled on the thread pool and possibly run in parallel. I'll delegate you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595842/c-what-happens-if-after-await-thread-is-busy/59595985#59595985) to shed some light on that. That basically means that if your `SendAsync` looks something like this:

```
Task SendAsync(IMessage message)
{
    // Synchronous initialization code.

    await something;

    // Continuation code.
}
```

Then:

- The first part before await runs synchronously. If this part is heavyweight, you should introduce parallelism in `SendAll` so that the initialization code is run in parallel.
- `await` works as usual, waiting for work to complete without using up any threads.
- The continuation code will be scheduled on the thread pool, so if a few `await`s finish up at the same time their continuations *might* be run in parallel *if* there's enough threads in the thread pool.

All of the above is assuming that `await something` actually awaits asynchronously. If there's a chance that `await something` completes synchronously, then the continuation code will also run synchronously.

Now there is a catch. In the question you linked one of the answers states:

> `Task.WhenAll()` has a tendency to become unperformant with large scale/amount of tasks firing simultaneously - without moderation/throttling.

Now I don't know if that's true, since I weren't able to find any other source claiming that. I guess it's possible and in that case it might actually be beneficial to invoke PLINQ to deal with partitioning and throttling for you. However, you said you typically handle 1-5 functions, so you shouldn't worry about this.

So to summarize, parallelism is hard and the correct approach depends on how exactly your `SendAsync` method looks like. If it has heavyweight initialization code and that's what you want to parallelise, you should run all the calls to `SendAsync` in parallel. Otherwise, `async`/`await` will be implicitly using the thread pool anyway, so your call to PLINQ is redundant.