Return to initial thread in C# Console application after await Task.Run()
After Task.Run() is awaited in a C# (.Net Core) console app, the main thread is never returned to. How do I return to the main thread in a console app after Task.Run()/Task.Factory.StartNew() etc.
The main thread is the thread the app starts in (in this case 1 is the assigned thread ID.)
For example:
await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!"))


Typically its no problem that its a different thread afterwards why is it for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686862/why-the-default-synchronizationcontext-is-not-captured-in-a-console-app

You may want to ask yourself this question: what is the main thread doing while my program is awaiting a task? The main thread can't exit, because then the program would terminate immediately. So it is blocked, and remains blocked until the async Task Main completes. Basically this thread is underutilized. It does nothing else than launching the Main task, and then sleeping until the end of the program. No built-in mechanism exists to awake the sleeping thread and run code on it.
The C# compiler translates the async Task Main entry point to this:
public static void Main() // Compiler generated
{
    return MainCore().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task MainCore()
{
    // The body of the original Main goes here
}

Apparently Microsoft decided a long time ago that installing a message loop in a Console application, and funneling all await continuations on the main thread of the console application, would be against the spirit of a console application, and would probably be against the expectations of most C# developers who write console applications.
So, no, you can't return to the main thread of a console application after an await. At least not with the built-in tools provided by the standard .NET libraries.
